# embed swf. file programmatically asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have swf files and I read this files from database. My q. is how can I embed this files in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that the file itself is stored as a binary object in the database?  If that's the case then it sounds like the embed tag that references it will probably need to reference an intermediate page, and *that* page will be what returns the SWF.

This has been done plenty of times with images, and while I've never heard of it being done with SWF the principle is essentially the same.  Take a look here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210211001213/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/060100-1.shtml

It's an old example, but it should illustrate the principle well enough.  The intermediary page will get the binary file from the database and respond with a custom header and a stream of that binary data.  From the browser's perspective, the ASPX file being returned is a SWF file.